# Selenium navigate to next page using footer

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I’m using selenium with beautiful soup to try to scroll though post on a page.  I was trying to use the code below to load all of the 503 posts, but realized the page didn’t scroll and load.  It has numbers at the footer to click on and loads the next page.  Can anyone suggest how to click from page to page?  I’ve included the source code below.  For example if I wanted to just click to page 2 would I use a css selector to find the element?

Code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

emptLst=[]

for i in range(int(round(503/12))):

    print(i)

    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')

    time.sleep(3)
```

Source code:

```
<section class="search-results-pagination-section">
                      <artdeco-pagination class="artdeco-pagination    pv5">
<!---->
    <ul class="artdeco-pagination__pages artdeco-pagination__pages--number">
          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number active selected">
    <span>1</span>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 2" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-252="252">
      <span>2</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 3" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-255="255">
      <span>3</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 4" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-258="258">
      <span>4</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-261="261">
      <span>5</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 6" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-264="264">
      <span>6</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 7" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-267="267">
      <span>7</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 8" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-270="270">
      <span>8</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number">
  <button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-273="273">
    <span>…</span>
  </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 21" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-276="276">
      <span>21</span>
    </button>
</li>

    </ul>

<!----></artdeco-pagination>


                    </section>
```

Comment: can you share the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an attribute = value selector to target the buttons e.g.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-label="Page 2"]').click()
```

---

It would help to have a url to test with as I cannot be sure that the currently visible 21 is indeed the last page but you if it were you could gather all buttons and extract last page number from the last button in the list and then loop all pages by constructing the aria-label attribute value for clicking:

```
buttons = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.artdeco-pagination__pages button')
pages = int(buttons[-1].text)

if pages > 1:
    for page in range(2, pages + 1):
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-label="Page {}"]'.format(page)).click()
        #do something
```

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.